# $C:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbf R^3\ |\ \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}=1 \}$ cannot be a $\leq 2$-dimensional submanifold in $\mathbf R^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Denote $C:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbf R^3\ |\ \max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\}=1 \}$.

1. Show that $C$ cannot be endowed with the structure of a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbf R^3$.
2. Show that $C$ cannot be endowed with the structure of a $0$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbf R^3$.

Is there a single answer to both or should we treat them separately?

For (2), I think, if it were embedded in $\mathbf R^2$, $C$ would be compact and so diffeomorphic to $\mathbf S^2$ which cannot happen.

Thanks!

Comment: @yili $\mathrm{dim} T_0C=3$. Is your point that if it were embedded then the tangent space in the image will have a lower dimension? If so, would you please explain if this is related to my attempt!

Comment: my solution seems not very rigorous, assume $C$ has structure makes it a $m$ dimensional  submanifold, since as submanifold ,it has the subspace topology, on this submanifold, exist **one** smooth structure induced from $\Bbb{R}^3$ , and you can see the coordinate curve at $0$ is a smooth curve, and the velocity are 3 independent vectors, therefore it has at least 3 dimensional at $T_0C$, since the dimension of tangent space = dimension of the topological manifold, you see topological dimension of $C$ can no be less than $3$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, you are absolutely right. I mixed up the questions. I am editing it right now.

Comment: I just wanna point out that your surface $C$ (the hollow box) is different from $[-1, 1]^3$ (the solid box).

Comment: @ArcticChar Edited, thanks (though I wrote the surface of $[-1,1]^3$)